# Como eu posso pegar o id em classes com nomes iguais?

Tags: jquery

Como eu posso pegar o id da alternativa e saber se é a 0, 1 ou a 2.

```
<div class="quest-alternatives">
<p class="brand-alternative">
<span class="brand-id hidden" style="display: none;">123</span>
<span class="radio-button" id="brand-0"></span>
<label for="brand-0" class="brand-name">Opção 0</label></p>

<p class="brand-alternative">
<span class="brand-id hidden" style="display: none;">456</span>
<span class="radio-button" id="brand-1"></span>
<label for="brand-1" class="brand-name">Opção 1</label></p>

<p class="brand-alternative">
<span class="brand-id hidden" style="display: none;">789</span>
<span class="radio-button" id="brand-2"></span>
<label for="brand-2" class="brand-name">Opção 2</label></p></div>
```

usei o `$('span.brand-id.hidden').html()`
porem ele só me retornou o id da primeira alternativa
também tentei usar o `$.each` só que não entendi muito bem como ele funciona.

Comment: Filipe, qual é o ID que quer pegar? da `<span>` a seguir a `<<span class="brand-id hidden" style="display: none;">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você tem um seletor que retorna mais de um elemento, e você chama o método `html` nele, ele só retorna o resultado do primeiro elemento. Diversas funções do jQuery funcionam da mesma maneira.

Se você quer os conteúdos de todos os elementos (numa lista, por exemplo), pode usar a função [`.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
$('span.brand-id.hidden').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Jhd/). O resultado é um "array-like" que você pode salvar ou usar em um `for` normal (i.e. usando o `length`, acessando os elementos como `lista[0]` etc).

Comment: sugestão: `return this.innerHTML` em vez de `return $(this).html();` - `+1`por ter compreendido a pergunta e dado a resposta acertada :) Eu fiquei baralhado com a pergunta.

Comment: @Sergio Valeu, também pensei nisso, mas preferi manter o padrão jQuery no código inteiro. Mas de fato, é trabalho desnecessário, por performance sua sugestão é melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer uma função para verificar uma propriedade do próprio elemento(removendo código html desnecessário), algo como (removi o `span hidden` com valor no html e setei um valor para `name`) :

```
<div class="quest-alternatives">
<p class="brand-alternative">

<span class="radio-button brand-id" name="123" id="brand-0"></span>
<label for="brand-0" class="brand-name">Opção 0</label></p>

<p class="brand-alternative">

<span class="radio-button brand-id" name="456" id="brand-1"></span>
<label for="brand-1" class="brand-name">Opção 1</label></p>

<p class="brand-alternative">

<span class="radio-button brand-id" name="789" id="brand-2"></span>
<label for="brand-2" class="brand-name">Opção 2</label></p></div>
```

O JQuery deve ser isto:

```
$('.brand-id').each(function(index, value){
 var id = $(this).attr("id"); // retorna brand-0/brand-1/brand-2
 var valor = $(this).attr("name"); // retorna 123/456/789
 alert(id + "-" + valor);
});
```

Aqui vai o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandroaje/5cy7E/) com o código.